# Using exec on each file in a bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a basic `find` command for a assignment (without using `find`). Right now I have an array of files I want to `exec` something on. The syntax would look like this:

`-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH`

And I have an array called `current` that holds all of the files. My array only holds `/bin/mv`, `{}`, and `~/.TRASH` (since I shift the `-exec` out) and are in an array called `arguments`.

I need it so that every file gets passed into `{}`  and exec is called on it.

I'm thinking I should use `sed` to replace the contents of `{}` like this (within a for loop):

```
for i in "${current[@]}"; do
    sed "s@$i@{}" 
    #exec stuff?
done
```

How do I exec the other arguments though?

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I meant I'm writing a basic `find` command, but I am not allowed to use `find`.

Comment: @anubhava I need to replace the string `{}` with the file i'm passing in from `current`, then I need to `exec mv` that file to trash. So I'm replacing each instance of `{}` with that file, then executing a command on that file. I don't know, if thats how it's supposed to work though or if there is an easier way.

Comment: Sorry you won't get answer here without providing total clarity. Do you have literal `{}` in your input files?

Comment: @anubhava Sorry about that :( I do not. Most of the files are just regular files, ie. `test.txt`. So if I have `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` in my `current` array, and the user passes in `-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH`, then it will look like this: `for i in current[0] ... exec mv test1.txt ~/.TRASH` ... `for i in current[1] ... exec mv test2.txt ~/.TRASH` It goes through every file and executes the `mv` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can something like this:

```
cmd='-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH'    
current=(test1.txt test2.txt)

for f in "${current[@]}"; do 
   eval $(sed "s/{}/$f/;s/-exec //" <<< "$cmd")
done
```

Be very careful with `eval` command though as it can do nasty things if input comes from untrusted sources.

---

Here is an attempt to avoid `eval` (thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for his comments):

```
current=( test1.txt test2.txt )
arguments=( "/bin/mv" "{}" ~/.TRASH )

for f in "${current[@]}"; do
   "${arguments[@]/\{\}/$f}"
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just outputs  `/bin/mv` a ton of times :(

Comment: I expected it to move the files to trash. Also if you do /bin/ls it will just output /bin/ls/ many times. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Actually doing exec $cmd after resolve the issue. Thank you for getting me on the right track :)

Comment: This is really dangerous in many ways! **you really should not call `eval` at all!** filenames should be handle like user input: potentially dangerously destructive. Never call `eval` on code you don't control.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you and wrote about it in the answer. Problem is that OP wrote: **user passes in `-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH`** Now we have `-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH`  in a string and then need to run the command. OP's own attempt of running via `exec` will pose same amount of risk.

Comment: OP wrote: _My array that holds `/bin/mv`, `{}`, and `~/.TRASH` are in an array called `arguments`_. This is bliss! OP uses the proper design here! arguments are in an array, not in a string!

Comment: Hmm there is conflicting information in comments section where OP wrote **user passes in `-exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH`**

Comment: @anubhava Sorry about the conflicting information, I was super tired when writing this. I've update the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Your are lucky that your design is not too bad, that your arguments are in an array.

**But you certainly don't want to use `eval`.**

So, if I understand correctly, you have an array of files:

```
current=( [0]='/path/to/file'1 [1]='/path/to/file2' ... )
```

and an array of arguments:

```
arguments=( [0]='/bin/mv' [1]='{}' [2]='/home/alex/.TRASH' )
```

Note that you don't have the tilde here, since Bash already expanded it.

To perform what you want:

```
for i in "${current[@]}"; do
    ( "${arguments[@]//'{}'/"$i"}" )
done
```

Observe the quotes.

This will replace all the occurrences of `{}` in the fields of `arguments` by the expansion of `$i`, i.e., by the filename<sup>1</sup>, and execute this expansion. Note that each field of the array will be expanded to one argument (thanks to the quotes), so that all this is really safe regarding spaces, glob characters, etc. This is really the safest and most correct way to proceed. Every solution using `eval` is potentially dangerous and broken (unless some special quotings is used, e.g., with `printf '%q'`, but this would make the method uselessly awkward). By the way, using `sed` is also broken in at least two ways.

Note that I enclosed the expansion in a subshell, so that it's impossible for the user to interfere with your script. Without this, and depending on how your full script is written, it's very easy to make your script break by (maliciously) changing some variables stuff or `cd`-ing somewhere else. Running your argument in a subshell, or in a separate process (e.g., separate instance of bash or sh—but this would add extra overhead) is really mandatory for obvious security reasons!

Note that with your script, user has a direct access to all the Bash builtins (this is a huge pro), compared to some more standard `find` versions<sup>2</sup>!

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that [POSIX clearly specifies that this behavior is implementation-defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html):

> If a *utility_name* or *argument* string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether *find* replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.

In our case, we chose to replace all occurrences of `{}` with the filename. This is the same behavior as, e.g., GNU `find`. From `man find`:

> The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.

---

<sup>2</sup> [POSIX also specifies that calling builtins is not defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html):

> If the *utility_name* names any of the special built-in utilities (see [Special Built-In Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14)), the results are undefined.

In your case, it's well defined!

---

I think that trying to implement (in pure Bash) a `find` command is a wonderful exercise that should teach you a lot… especially if you get relevant feedback. I'd be happy to review your code!